# Googlebot incrementing page id

Tags: apache-2.2, php, googlebot

So here is an example of a hit I'm getting from the googlebot:

```
66.249.73.171 - - [19/Feb/2013:16:12:39 -0500] "GET /eghm-blah.php?pid=2855 HTTP/1.1" 200 1684 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
```

My posts are setup to increment the `pid` for new posts...however the highest `pid` I have is 13. The googlebot has been slowly incrementing the page numbers and looking for new posts. When it  makes the access attempt it will not 404 as `eghm-blah.php` will display a message that it can't find your post.

Is there anyway to stop googlebot from hitting my server multiple times per day looking for pid's which don't exist?

Comment: Make `eghm-blah.php` correctly 404 when the post doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`eghm-blah.php` should be setting the return code to 404. You can still display whatever you want on the page but the return code needs to be 404.

Comment: Ah ok. I thought there may have been a way to stop it without throwing a 404.

Comment: You also likely have some reference to pid+1 on your 404 page. Google is likely following that